# F# Async parallel execution

Tags: parallel-processing, f#

The following F# code is run in a 16 cores CPU:

```
let locks = [| obj(); obj(); obj() |]
let c = seq {0..9} |> Seq.map (fun i -> async { lock locks[i % 3] (fun() -> Async.Sleep(1)) })
Async.Parallel(c, 3) |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Are the following assertions true?

- The first computations started (in parallel) are c[0], c[1], c[2] (not 3 random in the sequence of 10)
- As soon as one of the 3 completes, another will be started immediately (without waiting until completion of the other 2).
- Computations will be started in the order generated by the sequence. In other words, once one of c[0], c[1], c[2] completes the next started will be c[3] (not one random of c[3]..c[9])

Let's then suppose that c[0], c[1], c[2] start at times t0 < t1 < t2, and that all 10 computations take identical CPU time to be executed.

- The start order will be c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4], c[5], c[6], c[7], c[8], c[9]
- Across the full execution, no contention will occur (as it never occurs that computations running in parallel try to acquire the same lock)